# How to use * wildcard character in robots.txt files?

Tags: web-crawler

My website is crawled high frequently. I have robots.txt is below:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: .htm$
Disallow: /*?*
Disallow: /mls.php?*
```

but 'Googlebot 2' doesn't obey the robots rules.

The following is a log snappet: 2023-11-03 06:46:47.856 PDT GET 200 6.62KB 433 ms Googlebot 2 https://vanfangchan.com/mls.php?mls=1355081&lang=zh_s

Does my robots.txt is right, and anyone know that 'Googlebot 2' is owned by Google?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Google Search Console` to verify legitimacy of the crawler, and it also doubles as an issue identifier for your `robots.txt` file.

In the case that this is not from google, you might want to block it. There are various ways to do it depending on where your server is running (e.g blocking access using `.htaccess rules` or configs in web servers)